# Попарно переставить строки в двумерном массиве C#

Tags: c#, массивы, строки, матрицы

Нужно **попарно поменять строки** в матрице(1-ю со 2-ой, 3-ю с 4-ой и т.д.). Это мое решение, но почему то при выводе выводится изначальная матрица, т.е. код не работает или работает не правильно. Буду рад любым предложениям.

```
int t = 0;

while (t < array.GetLength(0))
{
    for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        var a = array[t, j];
        array[t, j] = array[t + 1, j];
        array[t + 1, j] = a;
    }

    t = t + 2;

    //cheking for overload
    if(t >= array.GetLength(0))
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда в программе больше одной ошибки, то порой непросто понять, в правильную ли сторону движешься - потому что результат всё равно неправильный. Разбивайте задачу на отдельные компоненты, чертите на листочке значения переменных в цикле если в уме дебаг сложно или отлаживайтесь на живую.

Вот вам готовый отлаженный код, написал с нуля:

```
private void SwitchRows(int[,] array)
{
    var iMax = array.GetLength(0);
    var jMax = array.GetLength(1);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < iMax; i=i+2)
    {
        if(i+1==iMax)
            break;
            
        for (int j = 0; j < jMax; j++)
        {
            var a = array[i, j];
            array[i, j] = array[i+1, j];
            array[i+1, j] = a;
        }
    }
}
```

Результат до и после:

```
var array = new int[,]
{
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6},
    {7,8,9},
};
SwitchRows(array);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И постфактум сравним две версии, они же практически одинаковы (мысленно замените ваш while на мой for):

- проверка вынесена наверх
- в проверке должно быть не `t >= array.GetLength(0)` а `t + 1 >= array.GetLength(0)`

Вот и вся разница.

Мммм... и даже всего одна ошибка, не две: проверка наверху из-за разницы между циклами while и for.

А ошибка в `t` vs `t + 1` - это вам нужно на листочке нарисовать значения переменных для массива с чётным и нечётным числом строк, можно даже не углубляться во внутренний цикл.

Comment: Большое спасибо)